# How to print batches of data that are used at each epoch (keras)?

Tags: keras, neural-network

I'm using my own generator and I'd like to check if it works correctly. Is it possible to print each batch that is fed to the model at each epoch?

Answer (score -1):

[Custom callbacks](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_callback). There are demos there, and all of the points at which you can execute a callback are listed in [this documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback).